# What is the difference between operator() and operator< in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

Whenever I have C++ entities that I want to compare I just implement `operator<`. However, reading other people's code I saw that the same can be achieved by implementing `operator()`.

What is the difference between the two? When should each of these operators be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: Huh? `operator()` for comparison? I have the strong feeling you're mixing completely different things (like `<` vs a comparator that implements `()`).

Comment: @ChristianRau: That's the crux of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator<` is the canonical way to define a comparison operator:

```
struct A { /* some members */ };
struct B { /* some members */ };

// comparison operator
bool operator<(const A&, const B&);
```

This gives you the conventional usage:

```
int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

   const bool result = (a < b);
}
```

---

What you've seen is people creating *functors*; that is, **entire classes** whose **sole purpose** is to wrap a comparison. To make these look a bit like functions to calling code, they use `operator()`:

```
struct A { /* some members */ };
struct B { /* some members */ };

// comparison functor
struct comparator
{
   bool operator()(const A&, const B&);
};
```

This gives you a less conventional usage in code equivalent to my previous example:

```
int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;

   comparator c;
   const bool result = c(a,b);
}
```

However, you wouldn't use it for this. Functors are for passing to algorithms (particularly in generic code). They also have the added benefit of being able to *hold state*, since you have constructor arguments to play with. This makes them more flexible than a simple function pointer.

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<A> a(5);
   B b;

   comparator c;
   std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), c);

   // or, simply:
   std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comparator());

   // all more easily extensible than:
   std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), &someComparisonFunction);
}
```